# My css3 menu isn't clickable on mobile phones

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu

My website at http://liveapplesprings.com isn't working on the CSS menu on mobile phones on pages other than the homepage.  The home page and sub pages are based on the same dreamweaver template, so I don't understand why it would work there and not in the other pages.  The menu shows up but it isn't clickable.  When I use the brower's "Inspect element" it shows the link there, but just won't allow me to click it.

```css
ul#css3menu1{
 margin:0;list-style:none;padding:0;background-color:none;border-width:0;border-style:solid;border-color:;font-size:0;z-index:999;position:relative;display:inline-block;zoom:1;border-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius:0px;-webkit-border-radius:0px;
 *display:inline;}
ul#css3menu1 li{
 display:block;white-space:nowrap;font-size:0;float:left;}
* html ul#css3menu1 li a{
 display:inline-block;}
ul#css3menu1>li{
 margin:0;}
ul#css3menu1 a:active, ul#css3menu1 a:focus{
 outline-style:none;}
ul#css3menu1 a{
 display:block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;font:16px Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#1b5732;cursor:default;padding:10px;background-color:;background-repeat:repeat;border-width:0px;border-style:none;border-color:;}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li a.pressed{
 border-style:none;color:812529;}
ul#css3menu1 > li.switch{
 display:none;cursor:pointer;width:25px;height:20px;padding:10px;}
ul#css3menu1 > li.switch:before{
 content:"";position:absolute;display:block;height:4px;width:25px;border-radius:4px;background:#1b5732;-moz-box-shadow:0 8px #1b5732, 0 16px #1b5732;-webkit-box-shadow:0 8px #1b5732, 0 16px #1b5732;box-shadow:0 8px #1b5732, 0 16px #1b5732;}
ul#css3menu1 > li.switch:hover:before{
 background:812529;-moz-box-shadow:0 8px 812529, 0 16px 812529;-webkit-box-shadow:0 8px 812529, 0 16px 812529;box-shadow:0 8px 812529, 0 16px 812529;}
.c3m-switch-input{
 display:none;}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li > a.pressed{
 border-style:none;color:812529;text-decoration:none;}
ul#css3menu1 li.topmenu>a{
 background-color:transparent;border-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius:0px;-webkit-border-radius:0px;}
ul#css3menu1 li.topmenu:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li.topmenu > a.pressed{
 background-color:transparent;}
@media screen and (max-width: 899px) {
 ul#css3menu1 > li {
  position: initial;}
 ul#css3menu1 ul .submenu,ul#css3menu1 li > ul {
  left: 0; right:auto; top: 100%;}
 ul#css3menu1 .submenu,ul#css3menu1 ul,ul#css3menu1 .column {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;padding-right: 0;width: 100% !important;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 898px) {
 ul#css3menu1 {
  width: 100%;}
 ul#css3menu1 > li {
  display: none;  position: relative;  width: 100% !important;}
 ul#css3menu1 > li.switch,.c3m-switch-input:checked + ul#css3menu1 > li + li {
  display: block;}
 ul#css3menu1 > li.switch > label {  position: absolute;cursor: pointer;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;}}
```

```html
<div id="navblock">
<div class="container">
<div id="topnav">
<input type="checkbox" id="css3menu-switcher" class="c3m-switch-input">
<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
 <li class="switch"><label onclick="" for="css3menu-switcher"></label></li>
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="index.html" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">HOME</a></li>
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="about.html" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">ABOUT US</a></li>
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="lots.html" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">LOTS AVAILABLE</a></li>
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="recreation.html" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">RECREATION</a></li>
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="contact.php" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">CONTACT</a></li>
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="news.html" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">NEWS</a></li>
</ul></div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I've used that menu before. Look at this [http://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/RaBJwG]

```css
ul#css3menu1, ul#css3menu1 ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0; background-color:none;
  border-style: none;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover > * {
  display:block;
}
ul#css3menu1 li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  float: left;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
ul#css3menu1{
  font-size: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  padding: 0;
  *display: inline;
}
* html ul#css3menu1 li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul#css3menu1 > li {
  margin: 0;
}
ul#css3menu1 a:active, ul#css3menu1 a:focus {
  outline-style: none;
}
ul#css3menu1 a {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: bold 14px Ubuntu;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: #FFF 0 0 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  background-image: url("mainbk.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #C0C0C0;
}
ul#css3menu1 ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
ul#css3menu1 ul a {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: none;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  font: 14px Ubuntu;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover > a, ul#css3menu1 li a.pressed {
  background-color: #f8ac00;
  border-color: #C0C0C0;
  border-style: solid;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: #FFF 0 0 1px;
  background-image: url("mainbk.png");
  background-position: 0 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul#css3menu1 span {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
ul#css3menu1 ul li:hover > a, ul#css3menu1 ul li a.pressed {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: none;
  color: #868686;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul#css3menu1 li.topfirst > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
ul#css3menu1 li.toplast>a{
 border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="css3menu-switcher" class="c3m-switch-input">
<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
 <li class="switch"><label onclick="" for="css3menu-switcher"></label></li>
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="index.html" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">HOME</a></li>
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="about.html" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">ABOUT US</a></li>
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="lots.html" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">LOTS AVAILABLE</a></li>
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="recreation.html" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">RECREATION</a></li>
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="contact.php" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">CONTACT</a></li>
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="news.html" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">NEWS</a></li>
</ul></div>
</div>
```